# Find the index of an object in array by reference?

Tags: javascript

```
var obj =  {'foo':'bar'};

var array =  [obj, {'foo':'bar'}]
```

How do I find the index of an object in the array by using the reference in this case `obj` variable?

I would think to do something like: `array.findIndex((o) => o === obj)` but is this fail proof?

Comment: "is this fail proof" - yes. You probably want `findIndex` though - if you already have `obj`, then getting `obj` from `find` has little use.

Comment: It will match the first item in the array since that's a reference to the exact same entity in memory as `obj` references. It won't match the second item even though it looks the same, it references a different entity in memory. Keep in mind that if you reassign `obj`, the first item in the array will still reference the old object.

Comment: As @ASDFGerte mentioned, you might want to provide a little more context to your question.  [`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) is just going to give you the ***exact*** same object that you already have a reference to.  What are you trying to actually do?

Comment: `array.find((o) => o === obj)` will just return `obj` so what is the exact purpose?

Comment: It should be noted that comparing objects this way is testing reference equality only, and not the values stored within the object

Comment: @ASDFGerte I indeed wanted to get the index, I should change the main question. You can post that as answer if you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

`o === obj` means (if `o` and `obj` are both of type `object`) that `o` and `obj` are exactly the same objects (same instance). Two `object`s are `===` equal *if and only if* they reference the same instance.
So yes, it is "fail proof".

You can try

```js
var obj = {'foo':'bar'};

var array = [obj, {'foo':'bar'}]
console.log(array.findIndex((o) => o === obj)) // 0

var array = [{'foo':'bar'}, obj]
console.log(array.findIndex((o) => o === obj)) // 1

var array = [obj, obj]
console.log(array.findIndex((o) => o === obj)) // 0

var array = [{'foo':'bar'}, {'foo':'bar'}]
console.log(array.findIndex((o) => o === obj)) // -1

console.log(obj === obj) // true
console.log(obj === {'foo':'bar'}) // false
console.log({'foo':'bar'} === {'foo':'bar'}) // false
```

Answer (score 1):

For getting an index, you could take [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) which compares the parameter with each element with [strict equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality).

```js
const
    obj =  { id: '73', foo: 'bar', first: true },
    array =  [obj, { id: '73', foo: 'bar' }];

console.log(array.indexOf(obj)); // 0
```